# C# - Cast to nullable without mentioning type

Tags: c#, nullable

Is there a built-in function like `Doubt` below, that allows me to cast without mentioning the type?

```
T? Doubt<T>(T t) where T : struct
{
    return t;
}

int i = 42;
var ni = Doubt(i);
double d = 42.0;
var nd = Doubt(d);
```

This would prevent bugs like cross casting between `int` and `double`.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean.  There's no casting happening here, in either case the compiler is able to infer the type based on the value passed to the generic method.  Is there an example of something that isn't working as expected which might help elaborate on the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: `T` to `Nullable<T>` is a built in implicit conversion. You don't need a function to do it?

Comment: @David `var ni = (int?)i` requires typing in the `(int?)` explicitly. The OP is asking how to avoid that, in case someone accidentally types `(double?)` instead.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such method already in .NET. It's a very niche requirement, so I doubt there is one.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a built-in function.  I would suggest renaming the method.

```
public static Nullable<T> ToNullable<T>(T t) where T : struct
{ 
    return t;
}
```

This is just convenience wrapper for what many consider something very easy to construct otherwise.  I personally would not want to use this method.  Its weaknesses are that (A) when you require to set it to null, then you cannot use this method, and (B) if you want to cast 42 to be a `double?` then you must cast 42 from `int` to `double` anyway.  I would prefer my code be clear to anyone else coming behind me figuring out what I am doing.